# FlatList iterating over index

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to use an index such as:

```
    const peopleIndex = {
      Alex: {
       title: 'Programmer',
       job: 'Working with React'
      },
      Dave: {
        title: 'DBA',
        job: 'Managing the database'
      }
    }
```

for the **data** of a FlatList. I expect to have to use **Object.keys** and the **keyExtractor** property but I'm having trouble implementing that.

Comment: what is the "trouble"?

Comment: Lack of experience with FlatList maybe. I'm running this:

    `<FlatList
      data={Object.keys(peopleIndex)}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => peopleIndex[item]}
      renderItem={({item}) => {peopleIndex[item]}}
    />`

Getting no output and a warning:
Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `[object Object]`.
Keys should be unique...

Answer (score 0):

The below code which prepares a properly shaped array for the data property of FlatList achieves essentially what I want. Just probably not in a very elegant or efficient way.

```
peopleArr = [];
for(item in peopleIndex) {
  peopleArr.push({key: item});
}
```

Comment: Just a comment, not a very good idea to use a name as a Key. You won't be able to show people with duplicated names. RN will ignore them.

Comment: I came up with a bad example then. I understand the keys should be unique. The problem is that you can't load FlatList from an index. You have to transform it to a particular type of array that FlatList wants.

Comment: In your for loop, can't you just create an index and assign the index value to key?